# send message from angular app to child iframe in same origin

Tags: angular, iframe, angular8

I have angular 8 app and a component which has iframe in it. The iframe is from same origin(same domain).
i want to send data from a form in component to iframe.

How can i do it and what is  best way to send data for same origin iframe.